# How to see the algorithm of mcrypt_encrypt()

Tags: php

i have searched overall how does `mcrypt_encrypt()` is encrypting or what algorithm is used , i know its php built in function but im just interested on how its algorithm work .

On [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) its just show how to apply then , but my question is how to read how it works (or what algorithm of this ).

Thanks.

*Obs I want study this function not just (not important or something i must not ask)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/MCrypt/2.6.8/

Answer (score 1):

You can find it into the php repository, it is in C:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/77b164edfdbe88f767c458407c342019d2d87e65/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.c

line 1316